# Not seeing is a flower?

Tags: idioms

Can anyone explain what does this idiom means ? 
I read the English translation and googled it but I still don’t know what it really means and what does flower refer to .

**見ぬが花**

**“Not seeing is a flower.”**

Thank you guys.

Comment: 「花」 has a couple of dozen meanings.  Even Jisho gives you nine.  See #7 here: https://jisho.org/search/%E8%8A%B1

Comment: [Jisho.org](https://jisho.org/word/見ぬが花) says: *reality can not compete with imagination; prospect is often better than possession*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 花 has a figurative meaning, "the best thing". This use of 花 is in the same vein as the English idiom "Silence is *golden*".

The very literal translation would be "Not seeing is a flower", but it roughly means "It's best when it's unseen". It's typically used to point out that something may not be that good in reality, or that someone is having an illusion against something.